# How do I force Leningen to use use a particular version of swank-clojure?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Here's my project.clj:

```
(defproject hello-world "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"                                                                                                                                       
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]                                                                                                                                 
  :dev-dependencies [[swank-clojure "1.5.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :plugins [[lein-swank "1.4.3"]])
```

Leiningen downloads swank-clojure 1.4.0 every time I run `lein swank`.

(I'm using leiningen 1.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need both the `:plugins` swank and the `:dev-dependencies` one.
try with just the dev-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to always use the same version of swank-clojure (which is also lein-swank),
you can run (for leiningen 1.x):

```
lein plugin install swank-clojure "1.5.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

For leiningen 2.x you can add the following to :plugins in the profile.clj file of your lein directory:

```
[lein-swank "1.5.0-SNAPSHOT"]
```

and the plugin will be usable from all of your leiningen projects without having to specify the requirement in the project file.